# NodeJS 6 : How can I view the entire error stack trace?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Instead of getting the promise rejection warning while compiling/running

```
npm start

(node:22996) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

can I get the whole stack trace pointing out the line in my code with the error as it used to in nodejs 4?

```
SyntaxError: /Users/user/Documents/project/app.js: Unexpected token (30:57)
```

Comment: tried it, didn't show any additional information

Comment: Syntax errors reported at compile time have to stack trace, because no JavaScript has been executed yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the following to your code to get a stack trace as you expect:

```
process.on('unhandledRejection', r => console.error(r));
```

It will show you the line of code with the error.